# Why does linked list work for node name, but not the pointer?

Tags: c++, linked-list, reverse

I am writing the code for reversing a linked list. This is the code

```
Node* reverseLinkedList(Node *head)
{
    Node* temp = head;
    Node* prev = NULL;
    while(temp != nullptr) { 
        Node* next = temp->next;
        temp->next = prev;
        prev = temp;
        temp = next;
    }
    return prev;
}
```

And it works perfectly. However, since the next node is just temp->next, why can't I use

```
Node* reverseLinkedList(Node *head)
{
    Node* temp = head;
    Node* prev = NULL;
    while(temp != nullptr) { 
        Node* next = temp->next;
        temp->next = prev;
        prev = temp;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    return prev;
}
```

The above now does not work. I would appreciate some clarity on how nodes are working here.Thanks!

Comment: Think about what value `temp->next` has after you have changed it.

Comment: *The next node is `temp->next`*, no it isn't because you changed it here `temp->next = prev;`

Comment: If this is C++, use `nullptr` instead of `NULL`, but if you're going to use `NULL`, do so consistently.

Comment: The best way to understand pointers is to draw them. Using boxes for the nodes and variables, arrows for the pointers, start with a linked list of length 3, and, one step at a time, draw out the changes that happen as your code executes. This is not easy, but if you can do it correctly you will greatly increase your understanding of how pointers work.

Comment: In the second code, you're incorrectly assuming that the assignment `temp->next = prev` does not change `temp->next`.

Comment: If you are under the impression that `temp->next = prev;` also changes the value of `next`, then remember that there is nothing special about pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because the `temp->next` were overwritten earlier

```
Node* reverseLinkedList(Node *head)
{
    Node* temp = head;
    Node* prev = NULL;
    while(temp != nullptr) { 
        Node* next = temp->next;
        temp->next = prev; // <<< here you assign new value
        prev = temp;
        temp = temp->next; // <<< here you use new value
    }
    return prev;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The two code examples are not equivalent.

In the first one, you store the *current* value of `temp->next` in the variable `next`. The reason you do this is that you're about to overwrite the value with `temp->next = prev;` on the very next line.

If you don't make a copy of that pointer, then you'll have no way of knowing what the next node in the original list is.

In the second example, you see exactly what happens if you forget that you modified the value. It is overwritten with `prev`, and then later on when you advance to the "next" node, you are actually advancing to `prev`, which is always `NULL` and your loop terminates.

So, technically, in the second example you *do* actually keep the original `next` but it's never used so that line is completely redundant and can be optimized away. The compiler should issue a warning that you have an unused variable, and this is often an indication of an accidental bug.

Answer (score 0):

its not working because at the time when you do **temp = temp->next** the temp->next is pointing to prev.

Comment: Has no new information than the other answers